# Why does Django store charfield as a tuple?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a simple model in django

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nuts3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

To save a model object I will do this

```
Customer.create(session_id = "unique_session_id", nuts3 = "some text")
```

Now say that I need to overwrite the nuts3 in the saved model object with some other text

```
customer = Customer.objects.filter(session_id = "unique_session_id")
customer = customer[0]
customer.nuts3 = "some new text"
customer.save()
```

When viewing the saved customer object in admin, I see a tuple in the `nuts3` charfield `('some new text',)`. I have expected in the field only to have the string without a tuple. How come that Django added the string as a tuple?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Willem Van Onsem in the comment section, it is due to a trailing comma that I was unware of. My code snippet is as below and there is a trailing `,` at `nuts3,`, which should be removed. Thanks for helping me out with this!

```
if customer:
            customer = customer[0]
            customer.nuts3 = nuts3,
            customer.save()
```